# Date Format Fail

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I am trying to format the following input date: "**2019-02-12 18:00:40"**"
to the following format "**dd-MM-yyyy**". However, I am experiencing mixed results with the date formatter method I created below and the output is as follows 
"**Wed Aug 11 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 17"**

```
  private String formatDate(String dateT) throws ParseException
    {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date date = formatter.parse(dateT);
        return date.toString();
    }
```

Comment: You need two `SimpleDateFormat` instances, one for parsing and one for formatting.

Comment: @Robert that worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @Robert. This was the solution I ended up using with two simpledateformatters.

```
private String formatDate(String date) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat inputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date currentDate = inputDate.parse(date);

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String formattedDate = formatter.format(currentDate);
    return formattedDate;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, you'll need two formats to get your desired result.

If you can use Java8+, I suggest using [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) and [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) (instead of [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)):

```
String stamp = "2019-02-12 18:00:40";
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(stamp, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")));
```

**Output:**

> 12-02-2019

***Edit:***

If you really *must* use the outdated classes, you can apply the same principle with `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
String stamp = "2019-02-12 18:00:40";
SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = dt1.parse(stamp);
SimpleDateFormat dt2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
System.out.println(dt2.format(date));
```

Comment: I cannot use java 8+ due to minimum api requirements

Comment: @George I updated the answer but see you figured it out in the meantime yourself!